# An exact test statistic for the mean of a gamma distribution with unknown shape parameter

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, maximum-likelihood

This is question 8.16 from McCullagh and Nelder's book, *Generalized Linear Models, 2nd Edition*.

> Suppose that $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ are independent and identically distributed with gamma distribution $G(\mu, \nu)$, both parameters taken to be unknown.

Here I'll note that they write the density function for $G(\mu, \nu)$ as

$$(\Gamma(\nu))^{-1} \left(\frac{\nu y}{\mu}\right)^\nu \text{exp}\left(-\frac{\nu y}{\mu}\right) d(\log y)$$

Note that here, $\mu$ is the mean of the random variable, and $\nu$ is a shape parameter.

> Let $\bar{Y}$ be the arithmetic mean of the observations, and $\dot{Y}$ the geometric mean. Show that under the composite null hypothesis $\mathcal{H}_0: \mu = \mu_0$, $S_0 = \log (\dot{Y}/\mu_0) - \bar{Y}/\mu_0$ is a complete sufficient statistic for $\nu$.

This is not too hard, as one need only take the derivative of the log likelihood function and set it equal to zero. $\mu = \mu_0$ is treated as any other constant, so one finds that $S_0 = F(\nu)$ (using $F$ for some nontrivial expression involving $\nu$), which is what's needed.

What I need help with is what follows.

> Show, again under $\mathcal{H}_0$, that the conditional joint distribution of $Z_i = \log(Y_i/\mu_0)$ given $S_0$ is uniform over the surface
>
> $$\sum_i (z_i - \text{exp}(z_i)) = n S_0$$
>
> Discuss briefly how you might use this result (i) to construct an exact test of $\mathcal{H}_0$, and (ii) to construct an exact confidence interval for $\mu$.

I have no idea how to show that the joint distribution given the sufficient statistic is uniform, as requested. And I'm not sure how exactly this can be used to construct a test for the null hypothesis. I could imagine how the test could be used for a confidence interval, though; given the data, the CI would consist of all $\mu_0$ for which the test would not reject the null hypothesis at the desired level of significance, which is one minus the confidence level.

Comment: I might be way off, but you might consider the fact that $nS_0=\sum_{i=1}^{n}log(X_i)-X_i$ where $X_i\sim \text{gamma}(1, \nu)$. Then since we can treat a gamma as a sum of independent exponentials with rate parameter of 1, which can be treated as the -$log(U)$ where $U$ is a $\text{uniform}(0,1)$ there might be some intuition there as to why we get the uniform behavior.

Comment: @NoeVidales we can only treat as sum of exponentials if $\nu$ is an integer.